# Does Code Blocks have an active line?

Tags: codeblocks

The active line option when changing the syntax color doesn't do anything.

Does Code Blocks even have an active line? I don't see one; not even with the default theme.

Just like in xCode, whichever line I"m on, the entire line gets highlighted to make it easier to know where I am. I've tried looking online; didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> General settings(on the left list) -> Other editor settings -> check the option "**Highlight line under caret**"